# Create React App Build and Docker-Compose do not pass env variables

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, create-react-app

I am currently trying to do a multi step build of CRA application. My dockerfile is like below

```
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15

COPY --from=0 /usr/app/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=0 /usr/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 6000
```

My docker compose file of react section is like below

```
  web_front:
    build:
      context: Web Front-CRA
    ports:
      - "${WEB_FRONT_PORT}:6000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - /usr/app/node_modules
      - ./Web Front-CRA:/usr/app
```

When I try to run this using `docker-compose up --build` I am unable to read the `NODE_PATH=./src/` environment file (all environment variables actually at the `RUN npm run build` stage.

However, if I just change the dockerfile like below to run dev environment, it works perfectly - all env files are passed

```
FROM node:10-alpine

# work directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Copy dependencies first for effective caching
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 6000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I am currently using ubuntu 18 and docker-compose v1.23.2 and Docker 18.09.0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For the environment variables to be passed onto the dockerfile from the docker compose build stage, you have to use **args: in docker-compose build step**. Example below

```
web_front:
    build:
      context: Web Front-CRA
      args:
         NODE_PATH=./src/
    ports:
      - "${WEB_FRONT_PORT}:6000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - /usr/app/node_modules
      - ./Web Front-CRA:/usr/app
```

corresponding dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine
ARG NODE_PATH
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.15

COPY --from=0 /usr/app/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=0 /usr/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 6000
```

Access it in the dockerfile using `$NODE_PATH`. PS I am using an environment variable here and not an envfile. But I hope you get the point. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The `.env` file is a special, name-reserved file for docker-compose to set defaults for environment variables, so if you want to use it, you should rather not specify in your compose file, or use a different filename (eg: `myservice.env`) for your `env_file` section.

```
  web_front:
    env_file:
      - webfront.env
...
```

The docker docs mentions vaguely this under https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ at the *Compose file and CLI variables* / *Notes* section

> Environment variables defined in the .env file are not automatically visible inside containers.

To set container-applicable environment variables, follow the guidelines in the topic Environment variables in Compose, which describes how to pass shell environment variables through to containers, define environment variables in Compose files, and more at:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option